# Flink Generate Dynamic Stream from GenericRecord Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, apache-flink, avro

I have a use case where multiple types of Avro records are coming in single Kafka topic as we are suing TopicRecordNameStrategy for the subject in the schema registry.

Now I have written a consumer to read that topic and build a Datastream of GenericRecord. Now I can not sink this stream to hdfs/s3 in parquet format as this stream contains different types of schema records.
So I am filtering different records for each type by applying a filter and creating different streams and then sinking each stream separately.

Below is the code that I am using---
``

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient;
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaMetadata;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FilterFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringEncoder;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.avro.ParquetAvroWriters;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class EventStreamProcessor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventStreamProcessor.class);
    private static final String KAFKA_TOPICS = "events";
    private static Properties properties = new Properties();
    private static String schemaRegistryUrl = "";

    private static CachedSchemaRegistryClient registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 1000);

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        ParameterTool para = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        InputStream inputStreamProperties = EventStreamProcessor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(para.get("properties"));
        properties.load(inputStreamProperties);
        int numSlots = para.getInt("numslots", 1);
        int parallelism = para.getInt("parallelism");
        String outputPath = para.get("output");

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(parallelism);
        env.getConfig().enableForceAvro();

        env.enableCheckpointing(60000);

        ExecutionConfig executionConfig = env.getConfig();
        executionConfig.disableForceKryo();
        executionConfig.enableForceAvro();

        FlinkKafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer010 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(KAFKA_TOPICS,
                new KafkaGenericAvroDeserializationSchema(schemaRegistryUrl),
                properties);

        Path path = new Path(outputPath);

        DataStream<GenericRecord> dataStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer010).name("bike_flow_source");

        try {
            final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                    (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema("events-com.events.search_list")))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .build();

            dataStream.filter((FilterFunction<GenericRecord>) genericRecord -> {
                if (genericRecord.get(Constants.EVENT_NAME).toString().equals("search_list")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).addSink(sink).name("search_list_sink").setParallelism(parallelism);


            final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink_search_details = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                    (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema("events-com.events.search_details")))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .build();

            dataStream.filter((FilterFunction<GenericRecord>) genericRecord -> {
                if (genericRecord.get(Constants.EVENT_NAME).toString().equals("search_details")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).addSink(sink_search_details).name("search_details_sink").setParallelism(parallelism);



            final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> search_list = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                    (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema("events-com.events.search_list")))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .build();

            dataStream.filter((FilterFunction<GenericRecord>) genericRecord -> {
                if (genericRecord.get(Constants.EVENT_NAME).toString().equals("search_list")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).addSink(search_list).name("search_list_sink").setParallelism(parallelism);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("exception in sinking event");
        }
        env.execute("event_stream_processor");
    }
}
``
```

So this looks very inefficient to me as

1. Every time a new event is added I have to do code change.
2. I have to create multiple streams by the filter and all.

So please suggest to me is it possible to write a GenericRecord stream without creating multiple streams.
If not how can I make this code more dynamic using some config file so every time I do not have to write the same code again for a new event?

Please suggest some better way to solve this problem.

---

I am trying liks this but its not working ....

```
        for (EventConfig eventConfig : eventTypesList) {
            LOGGER.info("creating a stream for ", eventConfig.getEvent_name());
            String key = eventConfig.getEvent_name();
            final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                    (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema(eventConfig.getSchema_subject())))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .build();

            DataStream<GenericRecord> stream = dataStream.filter((FilterFunction<GenericRecord>) genericRecord -> {
                if (genericRecord.get(EVENT_NAME).toString().equals(eventConfig.getEvent_name())) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

            Tuple2<DataStream<GenericRecord>, StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord>> tuple2 = new Tuple2<>(stream, sink);
            streamMap.put(key, tuple2);
        }


        DataStream<GenericRecord> searchStream = streamMap.get(SEARCH_LIST_KEYLESS).getField(0);
        searchStream.map(new Enricher()).addSink(streamMap.get(SEARCH_LIST_KEYLESS).getField(1));
```

Please provide the correct way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well You can simply pass the list of possible message types as config parameter and then simply iterate over this. You would have something like this :

```
messageTypes.foreach( msgType => {
    final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                    (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema(msgType)))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .build();

            dataStream.filter((FilterFunction<GenericRecord>) genericRecord -> {
                if (genericRecord.get(Constants.EVENT_NAME).toString().equals(msgType)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).addSink(sink).name(msgType+"_sink").setParallelism(parallelism);

}})
```

This would mean that You only need to restart the job with changed config when new message type arrives.

Comment: Thanks, Dominik. I will try as you suggested.  Any way possible to write GenericRecord Stream itself, without generating multiple streams.

Comment: I have tried this and its work perfectly. The only thing is if I want named stream rather than sink if I want to keep these stream in some variable how I assign each stream to a named stream by reading a variable name from config.

Comment: Is there any way to do this in an automatic way? 
I have a similar use case where multiple types of records are coming in a single Kafka topic as we are using TopicRecordNameStrategy for the subject in the schema registry. The logic is the same for different types since we're using the schema registry to deserialize the message, I am wondering if is there a way to add sink when a new type is discovered. 
This way we don't need to redeploy when a new type is added. 
Anyone has done this before?